# Como injecto EJB's que chamam outros EJB's numa classe de teste JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, ejb

Estou a tentar testar uma classe em JUnit.

Acontece que a classe que estou a testar tem vários EJB's que chamam outros EJB's.

Como injecto numa classe de teste JUnit EJB's que chamam outros EJB's?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A forma que recomendo de fazer um teste unitário em um EJB é instanciar o EJB a ser testado e mockar os EJBs que ele chama (ou seja, suas dependências). [Dependendo da forma](https://medium.com/@dherik/diferen%C3%A7as-nos-testes-unit%C3%A1rios-entre-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia-por-construtor-e-por-campo-qual-%C3%A9-8316eb903d0a) como o EJB está construído, talvez precise usar o método `set` dele para injetar as dependências ou, no pior caso, utilizar algum método de *reflection* para fazer a injeção por campo.

Por exemplo, veja o EJB abaixo:

```
@Stateless
public class PessoaEjb {

    private final EnderecoEjb enderecoEjb;

    @Inject
    public PessoaEjb(EnderecoEjb enderecoEjb) {
        this.enderecoEjb= enderecoEjb;
    }

    public PessoaEjb () {
        this.enderecoEjb = null;
    }

    public Pessoa validar(Pessoa pessoa) {
        if (pessoa.getNome() == null) {
            return new IllegalArgumentException("Nome inválido");
        }
        enderecoEjb.validar(pessoa.getEndereco());
        return pessoa;
    }
}
```

Um teste para ele ficaria algo como:

```
class PessoaEjbTest {

    @Test(expect = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void validar() {

        PessoaEjb pessoaEjb = new PessoaEjb(mock(EnderecoEjb.class)); // usei o Mockito aqui
        pessoaEjb.validar(new Pessoa(null));

    }

}
```